# Using module requests to login to a website with 2 different input pages

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

So I tried to join a Kahoot game using Python3 and Requests. The problem is that after you enter the game pin, you get redirected and then you have to enter the nickname. Does anyone know how to login when you get redirected? Here is the code:

```
import requests
url = "https://kahoot.it/"
GAME_PIN = input("Game Pin: ")
USERNAME = input("Username to display: ")
requests.post(url, allow_redirects=True, data={
    "inputSession": GAME_PIN,
    "Username": USERNAME
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the correct request is a `POST` request to `kahoot.it`? The only `POST` request I'm seeing is for google recaptcha.

Also maybe you should convert your python dictionary to a JSON object before passing it in, if the POST endpoint is of type `application/json`